# Byobu - New window with same ssh session?

Tags: terminal, zsh, gnu-screen, byobu

Is there a way to configure Byobu to use same ssh session in a new window. For e.g.

> 1. Open Byobu window
> 2. ssh into a remote host
> 3. Press 'F2' to open a new window. This opens the terminal with my localhost while I want it to ssh into the host in step 2 and possibly same path.

If it's not possible, are there any workarounds? Basically I don't want to ssh again and again if I want to open multiple tabs to work on a remote host.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest using a terminal multiplexer like `tmux` (or `screen`) on the remote host. This has the additional benefit that you are able to reconnect to sessions should the connection be interrupted.

Comment: You can configure `ssh` to use connection sharing as well; see the `-M` option and `ControlMaster` in `man 5 ssh_config`.